# How to pass a variable from app.yaml to main.py with Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to pass some configuration variables to my main.py from app.yaml.  I haven't been able to locate the syntax for accessing app.yaml from the code.

For example you want to have the user put their client number in app.yaml and access it from main.py to pass into main.html.  While it would be easy to create a variable in main.py to pass it, it seems to be something that would be better put into app.yaml.

Example:

app.yaml

```
    application: xyz
    version: 1
    runtime: python27
    ...
    clientID: (ID here)
```

main.py

```
    myID = appYAML.clientID
    ...
    values = {'xyz': blah.blah, 'myID': myID }
```

main.html

```
    ...
    <script>
      ...
      {% ifequal myID %}
        my_client = {{myID}}
      ...
    </script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the 1.6.5 release, App Engine support this[1]:

```
- In your app.yaml file, you can include an env_variables stanza that will set
  the given environment variables in your application's runtime.
```

Information on how to use this is available at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables.

Comment: This is very helpful, I will wait and work on this part of my app after 1.6.5 is released.

Thanks

Comment: Information on how to use this is available at:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Environment

Answer (score 5):

That's not supported, and you should put your application-specific settings into your own YAML file.

Comment: Curiously, this can be done in Java: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#System_Properties_and_Environment_Variables

Comment: I don't see any reason to not do it in app.yaml.  There can be times one would want to break out a separate configuration file but for 1 or 2 fields it really doesn't make sense.  At any rate I haven't even seen a method for accessing a variable in a different YAML file.  Do you have one?

Comment: @MarkFinch: you would need to read the different YAML file and use a YAML parser on it, unless you;re somehow using a framework that does this automatically (which seems unlikely). The problem with using app.yaml for this is that app.yaml isn't uploaded to the server as an application file, so you can't manually read and parse it from within your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can define variables in **app.yaml** to make them available to the program's **os.environ** dictionary:

```
env_variables:
  variable_name: '<YOUR VALUE>'
```

When you need to use this variable within the main.py you can call it in this way:

```
import os
CUSTOM_SETTINGS = os.environ['variable_name']
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables

Comment: This is great for setting the variables, but as a noob how do you retrieve and use them?

Comment: @SuatAtanPhD: why would you try to convert a string env var like `'myapp.settings'` to an int? Or did you mean to just have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']`?

Comment: @AdamChristianson in this old repository with a Python app is an example, here is the direct line where is used https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/f44618ae67f02cc107583c1b1cde0415844d1489/main.py#L30

Try to clone it and play with the project in order to understand how does it work